# How can I get the Redux store in a Selenium test?

Tags: selenium, redux

I have a React/Redux app, and I am writing Selenium WebDriver tests for it. It would be helpful to be able to examine the Redux store, to see if an operation left it in the state I expect. Is there a way to get programmatic access to the Redux store?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to stick the store in the window object, so that it was globally accessible:

```
window.reduxStore = createStore()
```

Then from my web driver, I can execute Javascript:

```
Map store = (Map) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).
    executeScript("return window.reduxStore.getState()")
```